# How to execute a Git patch?

Tags: git, patch

I have 2 repositories which are located on two different Git accounts, on completely separate tracks. The point is that these 2 repositories are sharing stuff.

Basically I would like to apply a change to one repository into the other one. The problem is that the folder structure is different:

**Repository S**

```
RepoS
|--src
   |--file1.js
```

**Repository D**

```
RepoD
|--lib
   |--src
      |--file1.js
```

So I make a change in `RepoS/src/file1.js` and would like to patch it into `RepoD\glib/src/file1.js`.

I tried:

```
git format-patch master -1 -o C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop
git am -3 <path-to-patch-created-in-line-before>
```

It fails in the second line:

```
Applying: My change title
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
A       src/file1.js
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
No changes -- Patch already applied.
```

So I tried (second line):

```
git am -3 <path-to-patch-created-in-line-before> --directory=lib
```

Still fails with error:

```
Applying: My change title
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M       lib/src/file1.js
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
No changes -- Patch already applied.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: I have edited with error messages

Answer (score 1):

`git am` usually applies patches from a mailbox of from stdin (note the `<`). So in your case you would have to use

```
git am --directory=lib < patch-file.patch
```

`git apply` on the other hand accepts the patchfile as the argument

```
git apply --directory=lib patch-file.patch
```

Comment: Given that Powershell does not fully support input redirection, I could not really apply `git am`. I tried `git apply` but the pathing failed. It says that the patching failed on `file1.js` No more info...

Comment: If I use `--verbose` I can see that it cannot find the fragment of code, but it is nonsense, that same fragment of code that he is looking for is in the file...

Comment: I have a feeling this is an encoding issue unfortunately... The text is there, so only explaination to me because `git am` fails is that some whitespace or line break is different. I actually successfully tried `git apply` while specifying `Out-File -Encoding ascii` when using `git diff`, and there I got the same error as in `git am`